# Typescript implement interface with same keys but different types

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
export interface Foo {
 a: string;
 b: string;
}
```

I want now to have another class which implements all keys of the interface but can have another type:

```
  export class Bar implements keysof(Foo) {
    a: SomeNewType;
    b: SomeNewType2;
  }
```

Is this possible in typescript?
Background: I want the `Bar` class' keys to be in sync with `Foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could potentially do it with a key map.

```
export interface Foo {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

type HasKeys<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: any;
}

export class Bar implements HasKeys<Foo> {

}
```

this will complain that `Bar` is missing `a` and `b` but it will be fine if you define them with any type. i.e.

```
export class Bar implements HasKeys<Foo> {
  a: number;
  b: object;
}
```